# Subtour elimination constraints of a symmetric Travelling Salesman in IBM Cplex

Tags: combinatorics, cplex, traveling-salesman

There is a sample code for travelling salesman problem in IBM Cplex. It defined the subtour elimination constraint as this:

```
   forall (s in subtours)
   sum (i in Cities : s.subtour[i] != 0)
      x[<minl(i, s.subtour[i]), maxl(i, s.subtour[i])>]
       <= s.size-1;
```

Can someone help me with the equivalent mathematical formulation of this code lines?

Comment: TSP is [not a valid abbreviation for Traveling Salesman Problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=TSP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone help me with the equivalent mathematical formulation of
>   this code lines?

[image]

Where:

```
xij = 1 if the the salesman traverses the link from city i to city j, 0 otherwise
S = a subtour, which is a subset of cities (which in turn is an ordered set).
i, j = two cities that belong to the subtour
```

The formulation is taken from [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/topic/ilog.odms.ide.help/examples/html/opl/models/TravelingSalesmanProblem/tsp.mod.html) and refers to the symmetric travelling salesman problem (the cost of going from `i` to `j` is the same as the cost of going from `j` to `i`). As such, variables `xij` are defined only for `i` < `j`.

I am not an `OPL` expect, but would explain the code as follows:

`subtours` is a tuple, which is like a C/C++ `struct`:

```
tuple Subtour { int size; int subtour[Cities]; }
{Subtour} subtours = ...;
```

I understand that `subtours` is defined as of type `Subtour`, which holds an array, defined over the cities, but of size pointed by the `size` variable (because not all cities may be part of a given subtour).

`forall (s in subtours)` is self-explanatory, corresponds to the for each part of the formulation.

`sum (i in Cities : s.subtour[i] != 0)`

I saw in the source code that `subtour` is an array that for each city `i`, `subtour[i]` is the successor of `i`. So, given a subtour, this line sums all the cities that have a successor city.

`x[<minl(i, s.subtour[i]), maxl(i, s.subtour[i])>] <= s.size-1;`

This refers to the variable `xij`, but takes care of the fact that `i < j`, because in a symmetric TSP it is not necessary to define variables for both `i < j` and `j < i`.

The subtour elimination constraints are added dynamically in the source code (and in most implementations, as their number is exponential, `2^(n-1 + n - 2)`, so `O(2^n)`).

In logic terms, the constraints say that any given set of cities should be connected and no subtours are allowed.

I hope this helps!